# invalid literal for int() when spliting value with comma

Tags: python, selenium, int

I was looking for answers on this, but every error like that did not mean the same problem...

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://example.com')

def repeat():
    import wx
    while 1 == 1:
        botloc = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
        botX,botY = map(int,botloc.split(','))
        print botloc
        print botX
        print botY
        wx.Yield()
def checker():
        while 1 == 1:
        if driver.current_url == 'http://logged.example.com/':
            repeat()
checker()
```

So after when i login myself, div value should be automatically printed in Shell but is comming:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

That div Split makes the crash, but typing manually in Shell `repeat()` is printing with infinite loop correctly all the time:

```
>>> repeat()
27,86
27
86
27,85
27
85
...
```

If i will remove `botX,botY = map(int,botloc.split(','))` then is ok, but i need that to split div using a comma, because i want get x and y. How can i fix that bug with the simplest way?

## EDIT: The website is still loading when my script is trying to get value and split that.

And here is the problem, so what can I use to controll the website, if it's already loaded or if it's not?

Comment: There's no breaking condition in your `while` loops, that's why they are going into infinite loops.

Comment: Move the `botloc` print up one line to see what is causing the problem.

Comment: Presumably somewhere you have a string like `"12,"`. This produces `["12", ""]` when split, and you then try to get an `int` from `""` (in your `map()` call), which fails.

Comment: Also, `while 1 == 1:`? If you want an infinite loop, use `while True:`.

Comment: I noticed what is the problem. `if driver.current_url == 'http://logged.example.com/':
            repeat()` is checking the url only, it doesn't mean the site will be already loaded, because it's taking 2-5 seconds. Function `driver.get` is aways waiting when the site is loaded.`if driver.current_url == 'http://logged.example.com/':` i just starting repeat(). Any idea how can i fix that? Should i add time.sleep what is depending on computer and internet - not flexible option. Or is maybe way to wait the loadining time (no longer, shorter)?

Comment: @Lattyware: No, there is everything fine with that. The website is still loading when repeat() is runing.

Comment: @Mezulith I don't see how what you said is relevant to anything I said.